# Preventing the Words while Chatter Post

Tags: chatter-feed-tracking

Can you find me an alternative Appexchange APP for Chatter Blacklist. I got the issue while installing in Production.

FYI, I have installed Chatter Blacklist. but it was failed. I just want to prevent the words while posting in Chatter post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be possible and I have the custom package. Are you interested?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? This is simply solicitation and will have to be removed without further detail as it'll be of no use to anyone in the future.